# iOS get user's frequent locations or figure out user's home location

Tags: geolocation, location, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Is it possible to get access to the frequent locations recorded on iOS devices, I'm trying to figure out where the user's home is without using backgrounding services in my own app itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may not access frequent locations already recorded on iPhone. The basic rule is whenever you want to learn something about a user, you had to obtain an explicit permission first. And that makes a perfect sense to me, as a user.

This rule is equally applicable to all the bits and pieces of personal info like photos, address book records and locations. You have to initiate visit monitoring from your app, and you will have to obtain a permission to always use location services to initiate this kind of monitoring.